# conflicts between cyrus sasl and openssl

Tags: openssl, md5, sasl

When building cyrus sasl version 2.1.25 on windows with cl compiler following this guide:
http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/cyrus2/windows.html

whith openssl version is 0.9.6g.

at this step:

```
#nmake /f NTMakefile
```

it fails with this error:
openssl-engine-0.9.6g\include\openssl/md5.h(103) : error C2371: 'MD5_CTX' : redefinition; different basic types

any idea about this error?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem as I don't want sasl plugins I deactivated compilation of plugin by editing NTMakefile:

SUBDIRS=lib plugins utils sample

to only:
SUBDIRS=lib

as I am interested only in sasl library.